# Update with stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I need to make a stored procedure that will update a given row in a table.

I have a table with three `foreign keys, Land_ID, Product_ID and CarType_ID`, and the last attribute is `Status_Car`.

The foreign keys are all referring to the tables `Product, Land and CarType`.

I need to make a stored procedure that can update the `Status_Car`, so it can be changed from available, to unavailable.

Here's my shot, i'm working in mySQL:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Car_Update(IN StatusCar varchar(10), CarType INT(10))

BEGIN
UPDATE standardprices
  Set Status_Car = StatusCar

WHERE CarType_ID = CarType




END//
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE standardprices Set Status_Car = StatusCar, CarType_ID = CarType WHERE CarType_ID = CarType
```

should work,

I'm not sure though if this is what you're looking for. If you have a foreign key constraint make sure whatever you update `Status_Car` to exists in the the `CarType` table.

Comment: I answered the same, but he changed the post :)

Comment: @zavg :( o okay I'll look again

Comment: Why down vote me when I .. clearly had a different version of the Q

Comment: This query would update all the records in the table each time it is run!

Comment: I'm just missing a where clause... there fixed